# how to set layout full bottom which inside another layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlmainLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer
                    android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot
                        android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_normal"
                        android:visibility="visible">

                        <!--<ImageView-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/deleteButton"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_centerInParent="true"-->

                        <!--android:paddingTop="50dp"-->
                        <!--android:padding="@dimen/margin_20dp" />-->
                    </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot>

                </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_dropView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                    android:padding="30dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="33dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_drop_cards"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10sp"
                        android:text="Drop Cards Here"
                        android:textColor="@color/blackDark"
                        android:textSize="10sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                </RelativeLayout>
             </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout file  i want set  delete_zone_view full bottom which is inside Drag Layer whose id is frame layout i tried to give gravity bottom
 but not going bottom its  coming  just top on Drag layer whose id is(frame layout) please suggest me how to keep one view bottom to another view which both inside parent view i am new in android .

Comment: for `delete_zone_view` set `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`

Comment: @Debdeep its alredy set

Comment: also provide gravity to the `frameLayout`

Comment: What type is  `DragLayer` exactly ?

Answer (score -1):

Considering that DragLayer and DropSpot are FrameLayout.

If you want DropSpot layer to overlap DragLayer, 
you can place both of them inside main RelativeLayout in same level with alightParentBottom=true to DropSpot.
Like

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlmainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer>

    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot
        android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or If you want them on same level without overlapping,
you can set layout_above attribute. 
Like

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlmainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot
        android:id="@+id/delete_zone_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DropSpot>

    <com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/delete_zone_view">
    </com.kdcos.contsync.utilities.dragview.DragLayer>

</RelativeLayout>
```